# Integrating DocuSign API for Document Preview and Signature Workflow

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently in the process of integrating the DocuSign API into my application to streamline document signing procedures. I am seeking insights on the following aspects:

1. **Document Preview:**

   - How can I effectively leverage the DocuSign API to create a comprehensive document preview, presenting all relevant data for thorough review before initiating the signing process?
2. **Obtaining a View Link:**

   - My goal is to obtain a view link from the DocuSign API, enabling seamless integration into Salesforce. This link should facilitate document preview directly within the Salesforce platform for users. What is the recommended approach to achieve this?
3. **Conditional Workflow:**

   - In addition, I am exploring a conditional workflow. Based on the document preview, I would like to make an informed decision on whether to proceed with sending the document for signatures. Are there any best practices or considerations for implementing such a conditional approach?

I welcome any valuable guidance, code snippets, or recommendations that can assist me in implementing these functionalities effectively. Your expertise is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The recipient view (embedded signing ceremony) enables the signer to review the document before signing. If they have questions they can use the comment feature. They can also choose the decline to sign option from the top menu of the signing ceremony